# Best way to transfer more values from one server to another via an HTTP call?

Tags: java, json, networking, http-post

I've to transfer data from one machine to another machine connected on a network. May be some 10-20 values to be transfered and that depends. All I do is pack up/ marshal the values in a json and transfer it to another server (say which is another machine connected on a network) via a http post call. Say the data flows from ServerA to ServerB in ServerA I have to pack up all the data to construct the json and in the ServerB I have to unmarshal it which eats up most of my code like the following

```
    String student_id = json.getString("sid");
    String student_role_number = json.getString("rnumber");
    String student_name = json.getString("name");
    String isDayScholar = json.optString("dayscholar", "false"); 
    String stream = json.optString("stream", ""); 
    String class_section = json.getString("section");
```

It's light when the value is 4-5 when there are more number of values like 20-25 I feel quite heavy in doing this get/set operations.Is there any better way to avoid/minimise this?

Comment: You may want to consider using a JSON library that supports data binding (automatic conversion of Java object to JSON and back). Jackson and Gson are two of the most popular.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - as you have found out they usually come out square. Use a decent serialization library (Jackson, GSON) and simply ask them the turn the Java classes into JSON and back again - with Java Beans you should end up with no more than 2 line of code at either end. You would even be better off using (Base64 encoded) Java serialization than your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

**It's light when the value is 4-5 when there are more number of values like 20-25**, If you could just hardcode all the required keys in some data structure then that might help. For example in your case all the necessary keys are sid,rnumber,name,dayscholar etc.

Keep a separate hardcoded data struct for your keys

```
org.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject();
java.util.Map<String , Object> otherMap = new java.util.HashMap<>();

String[] myLovedKeys = {"sid" , "rnumber" , "name" , "dayscholar" , "stream" , "section"};
for( int x = 0; x < myLovedKeys.length; x++ )
{  
    if( myLovedKeys[x].equals("dayscholar") || myLovedKeys[x].equals("stream") )
    {
        String value = "";
        if( myLovedKeys[x].equals("dayscholar") )
        {
            value = json.optString( myLovedKeys[x] , "false" );
            jsonObject.put( myLovedKeys[x] , value );
            otherMap.put( myLovedKeys[x] , value );
        }
        else
        {
           value = json.optString( myLovedKeys[x] , "" ); // stream key-value
           jsonObject.put( myLovedKeys[x] , value );
           otherMap.put( myLovedKeys[x] , value );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        String keyValue = json.getString( myLovedKeys[x] ); 
        jsonObject.put( myLovedKeys[x] , keyValue );
        otherMap.put( myLovedKeys[x] , keyValue );
    }
}
```

This will allow you to exactly know which key is currently being processed inside the loop and you can handle diverse behaviors depending on which key you are interested in dealing with

Now the reason why I have declared a JSONObject and a java.util.Map is because I simply want to elaborate the fact that if you are missing org.json.* library, then you can easily get away by using a java.util.Map, but if you have the org.json* library, then you can also deal with problem in a more comfortable manner. Now lets say we wanted to access the data then we could easily try things like

```
for( int x = 0; x < myLovedKeys.length; x++ )
{
    System.out.println( "java.util.Map: [" myLovedKeys[x] + "=" + otherMap.get( myLovedKeys[x] ) );
    System.out.println( "org.json.JSONObject: " + myLovedKeys[x] + "=" + jsobObject.getJSONObject( myLovedKeys[x] ) );  
}
```

In a similar fashion, you can modify and update those values

```
otherMap.put( myLovedKeys[0] , "SomeValue");
otherMap.put( myLovedKeys[1] , "Other Value" );
otherMap.put( "sid" , "SomeValue" );
otherMap.put( "rnumber" , "toSomeName");
//myLovedKeys[0] = "sid" , myLovedKeys[1] = "rnumber"
```

Similarly you can have the some changes reflected in the **jsonObject** variable. What you have to realize is that you have to deal with the pain of hardcoding all the key-names somewhere in your code, and yes that is going to take some typing :), Please let me know if that is still not enough to help your case

Comment: Here we are just trying to print the entire value within the stack `myLovedKeys` by declaring `keyValue` each time within the loop... But I would like to assign each value in a json to an indentifier/variable. In such case do we have any better options?

Comment: Maybe in the question you asked about ways of reducing hardcoded key specification in every line of statement, but I guess now you are interested in making changes to json?? You wish to change the key-values internally in json?? And no, I wasn't talking about printing, I was trying to make access to the json key-values generic, since we kept all the hardcoded key references separately

Comment: Please review the edit and do let me know if that is not what you are looking for

Comment: @ShayHanded thanks for your input :) I wish to collect all the values in the json - each one in a separate variable - and getting achieved this process - is heavy when there are more number of values than 4-5 say some 10-20 values - as i find my code as full of getters/setters.. So seeking for an alternative to achieve this...

Comment: @rajasubasubramanian33 Ok, I have made an edit, please understand the changes I have made and do let me know if that doesn't help your case